# grpc error when running tests for iOS App in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, grpc

I am receiving this error when trying to run my unit tests on my iOS project. The error only appears on M1 machines (intel machines seem to work just fine).

❌  ld: file cannot be open()ed, errno=2 path=/Users/iosdevteam/production/dev/****/UnitTestsBuild/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/route.upbdefs.o in '/Users/iosdevteam/production/dev/****/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/route.upbdefs.o'

❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The project has a mix of objc and swift

I am using cocoapods and my podfile looks something like this:

```
#Ignore all warnings in Pods Project
#inhibit_all_warnings!
#use_frameworks! #requires iOS 8+ and that all pods do not contain static libraries

platform :ios, '14.0'

workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
inhibit_all_warnings!

def firebasePods
    pod 'Firebase/Database',  '~> 10.4.0',   :inhibit_warnings => true
    
    pod 'Firebase',           '~> 10.4.0',  :inhibit_warnings => true

    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig',    :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks',    :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging',  :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics',     :inhibit_warnings => true
    
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore',        :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging',        :inhibit_warnings => true

end

def facebookPods
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit',                     '= 14.1.0',  :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit',                    '= 14.1.0',  :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit',                    '= 14.1.0',  :inhibit_warnings => true
end

def analytics
    pod 'CouchbaseLite-Swift',              '~> 2.8',   :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'libextobjc',                       '~> 0.6',   :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'GTMBase64',                        '~> 1.0',   :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'EmarsysSDK',                       '~> 3.3.0'
    
    pod 'Bolts-Swift',                      '~> 1.5'
    pod 'Bolts/Tasks',                      '~> 1.9'
    
    pod 'GoogleMaps',                       '~> 4.0',   :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'GoogleSignIn',                     '~> 7.0.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'GoogleIDFASupport',                '~> 3.14',  :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'GoogleTagManager',                 '~> 7.4.1', :inhibit_warnings => true

    pod 'lottie-ios',                       '~> 3.4.1', :inhibit_warnings => true
    
    pod 'TikTokBusinessSDK',                '~> 0.1.18', :inhibit_warnings => true
end

def convenience
    pod 'SDWebImage',                       '~> 5.0'
    pod 'KeychainAccess',                   '~> 4.1'
    pod 'SwiftPath',                        '~> 0.2'
    pod 'PDKeychainBindingsController',     '~> 0.0',   :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'OrderedDictionary',                '~> 1.4',   :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'DifferenceKit',                    '~> 1.2'
    pod 'eMAGLogin',                        :path => 'LocalPods/eMAGLogin', :inhibit_warnings => true
    
    pod 'NotificationBannerSwift',          :inhibit_warnings => true
end

def linting
    pod 'SwiftLint',                        '~> 0.48.0'
end

use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    project 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    analytics
    convenience
    firebasePods
    facebookPods
    linting
    
    target 'MyAppUnitTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      
      pod 'Nimble', '~> 9.2.1'
      pod 'Quick',  '~> 5.0.1'
    end
    
    target 'MyAppSnapshotTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      
      pod 'SnapshotTesting', '~> 1.8.1'
    end
end
```

I've tried:

- Updating ruby, cocoapods, homebrew, xcode
- Reinstalling ruby, cocoapods, homebrew, xcode
- Using a separate scheme for running unit tests
- Running my tests from the command line using `xcodebuild test`

Nothing seems to work

Has anyone seem this kind of error before?